# Does samba have a chage inactive equivalent?

Tags: password, samba, ldap

I am currently working with a slapd(ldap) + samba server, and trying to automatically disable accounts x amount of days after their password expires.

chage -Inactive does exactly this, which works for admin accounts -- which is not needed. After reading through samba documentation for several hours, I can't seem to locate any equivalent. I was trying to avoid having to use a script if possible, but that is not looking likely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5564988/2072269?

Comment: I did look into that before posting, but no overlays are allowed. Strict requirement to work with what is available, but writing own shell script is okay -- just more time consuming than.